# Meteor wrapAsync / Node Fiber Future Not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, node-fibers, meteor-methods

I am trying to get json data from one API using Meteor Method, I have tried to use meteor wrapAsync as well as Node Future. Below is my code:

**Template Helper - Client Side**

```
    getLocationTimebyAPI: function (company_location) {

    Meteor.call('getLocationTimebyAPIServerMethod', company_location, function(error, results){
    if(error){
        console.log('error',error.reason);
    } else {

        var localtime = results.data.data.time_zone[0].localtime
        var utcoffset = results.data.data.time_zone[0].utcOffset
        console.log(localtime+ ' '+utcoffset);

        var returntext = localtime+' (UTC '+utcoffset+')';
        return returntext;

     }
    });

    }
```

**Method 1: Using Meteor wrapAsync - Server Side**

```
'getLocationTimebyAPIServerMethod': function(company_location){

   var apiurl = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/tz.ashx?q='+company_location+'&format=json&key=XXXXXX';

    var convertAsyncToSync  = Meteor.wrapAsync( HTTP.get ),
    resultOfAsyncToSync = convertAsyncToSync( apiurl );

    return resultOfAsyncToSync;


}
```

**Method 2: Using Node Fiber Future- Server Side**

```
'getLocationTimebyAPIServerMethod': function(company_location){

    // use the node fibers npm
    var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

   var apiurl = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/tz.ashx?q='+company_location+'&format=json&key=XXXXXXXX';

    // Create our future instance.
    var future = new Future();

    HTTP.get( apiurl, {}, function( error, response ) {
      if ( error ) {
    future.return( error );
      } else {
    future.return( response );
      }
    });

    return future.wait();


}
```

In Both the methods, I am getting the values printed in the console but they are not getting returned.

Below is the screenshot:[image: Console Log]

I don't know where I am wrong, Could anyone please suggest me something.

**Edited : Added Template Code:**

```
    <tr>
        <td>Local Time:</td>

        <td><input id="company_location_time" name="company_location_time" type="text" size="23" placeholder="Lead Company Location Time" value="{{getLocationTimebyAPI company_location}}" readonly style="background:#7FAAFF;font-weight:bold;"><p style="font-size:8px;">Local Time Powered By <a style="font-size:8px;" href="http://www.worldweatheronline.com/search-weather.aspx?q={{company_location}}"  target="_blank">World Weather Online</a></p></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling `getLocationTimebyAPI `? Please provide an example

Comment: Above is the template code which is calling the template helper function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_get) say, you can just omit the async-callback and it will run synchronously. So this should work on the server:

```
'getLocationTimebyAPIServerMethod': function(company_location){
    // do checks
    var apiurl = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/tz.ashx?q='+company_location+'&format=json&key=XXXXXX';
    var result = HTTP.get( apiurl );
    return result;
}
```

On the client, the template helper should return `undefined` since when the helper is called there is no return value, yet. And there is no reactive data source in the helper that would cause the template to rerender. So, either use a `reactive-var` to store your result or use this package from stubailo [meteor-reactive-method](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method).

Let me know if that solves your issue!

Comment: It Solved my Issue Thank you very much @tomsp

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the method mentioned by @tomsp above:

First added https://atmospherejs.com/simple/reactive-method

**meteor add simple:reactive-method**

Then Changed my Code

**Server Side Method**

```
'getLocationTimebyAPIServerMethod': function(company_location){
    // do checks
    var apiurl = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/tz.ashx?q='+company_location+'&format=json&key=50a151065dc2a4ea69c1b93032805';
    var result = HTTP.get( apiurl );

      var localtime = result.data.data.time_zone[0].localtime
      var utcoffset = result.data.data.time_zone[0].utcOffset
      var returntext = localtime+' (UTC '+utcoffset+')';
      return returntext;
}
```

**Client Side Helper Function**

```
  getLocationTimebyAPI: function (company_location) {
    return ReactiveMethod.call("getLocationTimebyAPIServerMethod", company_location);

}
```

**Results are shown in the screenshot below:**

[image]